# Connect aftermarket radio to stock amplifier

Tags: audio, mini-cooper

I have MINI R53 with Harman/Kardon sound system. I know,  If I want to connect new stereo head, I have to buy "H/K enabler". But in my country I can't find it. Order it from another country is very expensive. So I started learn how does it work and please correct me if I'm wrong:
Stock head "speaks" with amplifier via high level input, but aftermarket heads mostly use low level input (RCA). Can I buy a simple MINI-to-ISO adapter and insert Line Output Converter (LOC) to this scheme and in this way create my own "H/K enabler"? I know, mostly people buy LOC to connect aftermarket amplifier to stock head, but can I do this in opposite way? Or this is more difficult?

P.S. Heard that some stock amplifiers check resistance and if it different what they expect - just don't play. How can I check it with my amplifier?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Usually with stock units the outputs out to the amp/speakers has the same outputs as an aftermarket head unit, just the color schemes might be different. If you can find (or figure out) which wires go to what, you can cut the stock harness and adapt in your new head unit's wiring. The "enabler" as you call it, just does this wiring for you ... at least that's my experience.

Comment: As is the case for almost every system on a Mini, I believe the sound system speaks "CANBUS".  So the H/K enabler is a CANBUS adapter that interfaces between the on-board systems and the aftermarket unit.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I don't think here is a only problem with the wiring. Because I checked photo with enabler and this enabler has connects2 box, for canbus as I can understand. @jwh20 I think you are right. Can you explain me why Mini without H/K doesn't need this canbus adapter? Because as I can see for standard Mini without amplifier, adapter is just simple, sorry, adapter from MINI plug to ISO. But as I understood, canbus sends information about ignition, fo example. I think radio still need this information